# replace specific element of Dataframe to value of Series

Tags: python, pandas

suppose I have a Dataframe `df` like

```
   a   b  c
0  1   2  3
1  nan 2  3
2  1   2  nan
```

I want to replace the element which larger than the Series  `df.count(axis=1)` to the element of the Series. Whith the `df` convert to

```
   a   b  c
0  1   2  3
1  nan 2  2
2  1   2  nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) with `upper` parameter:

```
#if necessary
#df = df.replace('nan', np.nan).astype(float)

out = df.clip(upper=df.count(axis=1), axis=0)
print (out)
     a  b    c
0  1.0  2  3.0
1  NaN  2  2.0
2  1.0  2  NaN
```

Another idea with [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
s = df.count(axis=1)
out = df.mask(df.gt(s, axis=0), s, axis=0)
```